# How to register a widgetized sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

In this site (http://tarjom.ir/demo/pwp/) on the left side there is a sidebar titled Left Side Bar.

I need to know how to register that sidebar so to be used as a widgetized sidebar. I have read some documentation and have tried a bunch of ways, but still fail to do so. I appreciate if any one help me in this issue.

thanks in advance

EDITED

this is the code that I have tried:

```
function sidebar_widget() {

    register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => __( 'Right Hand Sidebar' ),
  'id' => 'left-sidebar-login',
  'description' => __( 'ThemeMyLogin Widget Area' ),
  'before_title' => '<h1>',
  'after_title' => '</h1>'
));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'sidebar_widget' );
```

I have tried the above code, it is added to the widget drag-and-drop panel, but nothing changes in the page when I add widget. The sidebar still remains empty.

Comment: Have you looked at the `register_sidebar` function? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: Might help if you post what you've tried.

Comment: I have edited and added the code

Comment: yes I have taken a look and also have used the suggested snippet, but still fail

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
      'name' => __( 'Right Hand Sidebar' ),
      'id' => 'left-sidebar-login',
      'description' => __( 'ThemeMyLogin Widget Area' ),
      'before_title' => '<h1>',
      'after_title' => '</h1>'
    ));
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems that nothing has happened. it does not find my sidebar to put the widget into.

Comment: Are you calling that registered sidebar in your theme? If no then you will have to call your sidebar.
`<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Right Hand Sidebar") ) : endif; ?>`